# Как упаковать шары в сфере?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть алгоритм для построения шаров по поверхности сферы

```
private Vector3 GetVector(float length, int index)
{
    var inc = Mathf.PI * (3 - Mathf.Sqrt(5));
    var off = 2 / length;

    var y = index * off - 1 + (off / 2);
    var r = Mathf.Sqrt(1 - y * y);

    var value = index * inc;

    return new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(value) * r, y, Mathf.Sin(value) * r) * radius;
}
```

Может кто знает алгоритм именно для заполнения сферы шарами ?

Текущий результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем проблема? Шар хорош тем, что его как не верти получишь одно и то же. Это же вам не многогранники укладывать (которые могут быть не только лишь выпуклыми)

Comment: С формой все в порядке, но надо что бы сфера была тоже заполнена, а не как сейчас полая.

Comment: Приведенный код возвращает один вектор, я вообще не понимаю какое отношение он имеет к вопросу и приведенной картинке

Comment: Достаточно пройтись в цикле `var vector = GetVector(length, i);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Постройте [плотнейшую упаковку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80) шаров - ГЦК или ГПУ.

Для гексагональной упаковки формулы координат центров есть в вики. В единицах радиуса шарика

```
 x = 2*i + (j+k) mod 2
 y = Sqrt(3) * (j + 1/3 * (k mod 2))
 z = Sqrt(8/3) * k
```

Так что достаточно пройти по индексам слоя (k) и внутрислойным (i,j) и заполнить сферу. Код на Python :

```
import math
rbig = 3
rsmall = 1
rad = rbig / rsmall
sq8 = math.sqrt(8/3)
sq3 = math.sqrt(3)
krange = math.ceil(rad / sq8)
for k in range(-krange,krange+1):
    z = sq8 * k
    for j in range(-krange,krange+1):
        y = sq3 * (j + 1/3 * (k % 2))
        for i in range(-krange,krange+1):
            x = 2 * i + (j + k) % 2
            if x*x + y*y + z*z <= rad * rad:
                print(x*rsmall, y*rsmall, z*rsmall)
```

Comment: Что значит mod ?

Comment: @webkostya типовой оператор во всех языках программирования - остаток от целочисленного деления.

Comment: В шарпе  это   `%`

Comment: А можно не большой пример ?, ибо не совсем понятно про внутрислойный (i,j)

Comment: из вики "где i, j и k индексы по координатам x, y и z (начинающиеся с нуля)." но это получается не наполнение шаров, а построение лестницы )

Comment: Ну это просто один из способов упорядочения - строится [один плоский слой](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/Circle_packing_%28hexagonal%29.svg/330px-Circle_packing_%28hexagonal%29.svg.png) , а следующие сдвинуты относительно него. Тройной цикл - сначала по k, потом по i и j будет генерировать координаты как раз слой за слоем. Пример сейчас сделаю

Comment: Да, получилось, но не сфера а куб )

Comment: Нужно ограничения вводить сферические. Я сделал проверку - в принципе, можно лишнее почти не генерировать, но это сложнее будет

Comment: Большое Спасибо ! (все работает)

Comment: Не подскажете, есть ли возможность, при таком переборе, упаковывать только определенное кол-во шаров ?

Comment: А какой сценарий - увеличивать их радиус, или пустые места оставлять, или ещё как-то?

Comment: Сценарий такой, дается например 10 шаров, и их надо плотно упаковать

Comment: Для плотной упаковки небольшого количества шаров в сферу есть [специальные раскладки](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing_in_a_sphere) - например, для 5 это треугольник, и по шару сверху и снизу, для 6 октаэдр - т.е. 4 лежат квадратом, а не треугольником, как в плотнейших упаковках. **Общего правила нет**. Если ГПУ послойно делать - будет последовательность 1, 13, 57, 153, 323 шаров, можно лишние выбрасывать.

Comment: А каким образом высчитывается вектор x,y,z по данным раскладкам ?, вижу формулу, но не понял как ей пользоваться )

Comment: Кое что понял, эти формулы, это максимальный диаметр одной сферы, но нет самого алгоритма упаковки фиксированного числа сфер (